# How can I optimize value comparison of two arrays (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization

My two arrays are getting bigger and bigger and the comparison feels way too slow.

both arrays are not sorted and contain Strings only.

Here are some spects:

1. array1 is a subset equal array2
2. arrays don't have to be arrays. If lists or sets offer faster comparison, I can go with it
3. If array2 contains a string, array1 has not, write a logline
4. size of both arrays are >500 entries each.

Questions:

1. I read for-loops are faster than forEach. Is it true in this scenario?
2. Is using arrays the right choice in this scenario?
3. I thought about deleting duplicates, but can this make it slower for so many entries?

My function so far:

```js
elementsInEA.forEach(element => {
    if (!elementsInCSV.includes(element)) {
        sumNotInCSV += 1;
        logLine = stereotype + " '" + element + "' in EA, but not in CSV!";
        Session.Output(logLine);
        logFile.WriteLine("WARNING     " + logLine);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `===` operator instead of the `==` operator for strict equality comparison. This will ensure that both the values and the types of elements are compared

Or

Use the `every()` method to check if every element in one array is equal to the corresponding element in the other array. This method will return true if the arrays are equal and false otherwise.

Here you can see :

```
const checkEqualArray = (a, b) => {
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return a.every(function(element, index) {
    return element === b[index];
  });
} 

checkEqualArray([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5]);
```